AgoraIO UIKit disable video by default
How do I disable the video enabling by default with the UIKit ? I tried enableVideo = false in the rtcProps for AgoraUIKit but it did not work.
<AgoraUIKit
    rtcProps={{
         appId: appId,
         channel: "test",
         token: null, // add your token if using app in secured mode
         layout: layout.pin,
         enableVideo: false,
         enableScreensharing: true,
         customRtcClient: rtcClient as IAgoraRTCClient | undefined,
    }}
    rtmProps={{
         username: username || "user",
         displayUsername: true,
    }}
    callbacks={{
         EndCall: () => setVideocall(false),
    }}
/>

